# CSS/SCSS rails transforming div, but not nested image (rails)

Tags: css, hover, transform, css-transforms

I am trying to set up am image inside a main div where hovering over the div will make the attached image scale up over 2 seconds. Only the div itself (border) scales, not the attached image itself. Attempting to scale the image alone has no action as of this writing. This is being done in Rails 5.1.2. What am I missing?

views/community/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="scene">
    <div id="container1" class="image-div">
      <%= image_tag("hbehance.png", :id =>"first-image", :alt => "first symbol") %>
    </div>
</div>
```

stylesheets/community.css.scss:

```
.scene {
  position: relative;
  height: 35rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 95%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: asset_url("cityscape.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.image-div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform all 2s;
}

.image-div:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

The image was nested inside the div, but needed to be appended in order to respond in tandem:

javascript/community.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  firstDiv = document.getElementById('container1');
  firstImage = document.getElementById('first-image');
  firstDiv.append(firstImage);

  function testJS(){
    firstDiv.style.left = "50%";
  }
  testJS();//tests that JS file connects properly when first setup
})
```